# unescaping only HTML tags not supported?

Tags: templates, escaping, dust.js

I am using **dustjs** for front end templating.
   I have json data as
   var userData = {'desc': 'This content should be shown inside HTML SPAN TAG'};

Dust template: 
   {userData.desc}

But when I try to render this template, the desc content is shown on page "as the same string" and  tag is not shown as HTML span.

if I use {userData.desc|s|h}: span is shown on page as <span>

The only way I could use is {userData.desc|s} : this one shows the span as html tags properly. But |s will unescape script tags as well, which is a risk.

I want to **unescape only HTML tags from the json data content**, is there any way to achieve this requirement in dustjs..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a custom filter - this would suit your need better than a helper. just extend dust.filter with your own custom code that does what you want.

refer to my answer here: [How do I implement custom rendering logic in dust.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037968/how-do-i-implement-custom-rendering-logic-in-dust-js/11201445#11201445)

Answer (score 0):

The only available Dust filter for disabling auto-escaping is `|s`, which is, as you mentioned, not safe if there is a possibility that a script tag will be included in your data. According to the [Dust github page](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/):

> Filters do not accept arguments; if you need more sophisticated behavior use a section tag instead.

Although it is never made clear in the documentation how a section tag could be used to create more sophisticated filter behavior, I believe the most probable solution would be by creating an `@` helper.

Having said that, I would say the built-in filters are sufficient for most use cases. If it is possible that a script tag will get into `userData.desc`, then don't disable auto-escaping. If you're using templates, then your markup should be created in your template (not your JSON), anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot. you are correct html should be in templates, but for me its going to be delivered from thirdparty, so will need to find an alternative

Comment: I would suggest creating a custom helper, then.