# How to write case condition expression in DustJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I have a array type in Javascript:

```
var type=[0,1,2,3,4,5];
```

The corresponding key value pair collection is actually like this;

```
[{0:'Pointer'},{1:'Line'},{2:'Oval'},{3:'Rectangle'},{4:'Ellipse'},{5,'Star'}]
```

My .dust file displays the {type} mark, how should I display their corresponding values?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a custom filter. The approximate implementation would be:

```
var mapping = {
    '0':'Pointer',
    '1':'Line',
    '2':'Oval',
    '3':'Rectangle',
    '4':'Ellipse',
    '5':'Star'
};

dust.filters['typeFilter'] = function(value) {
    return mapping[value] || '';
}
```

And in you template: `{type|typeFilter}`

It's a bit simpler to store the mapping in an object than array. For you array version it would be like:

```
var mapping = [{0:'Pointer'},{1:'Line'},{2:'Oval'},{3:'Rectangle'},{4:'Ellipse'},{5:'Star'}];
dust.filters['typeFilter'] = function(value) {
    var typeId = parseInt(value);
    for(var len = mapping.length - 1; len >=0; len--) {
        if (mapping[len].hasOwnProperty(typeId)) {
            return mapping[len][typeId];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

A bit more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037968/how-do-i-implement-custom-rendering-logic-in-dust-js)